# c# cmdlet how to get the full command being used

Tags: c#, powershell

I am write cmdlets in c#, and I would like to know if it is possible in c# to retrieve the command with the name and paramter and value within the cmdlet class.

for example, I have a cmdlet

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "Data")]
public class GetDataCmdlet : Cmdlet
{

    [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = true)]
    public string DataSource ...

    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = false)]
    public string Login...
}
```

and then I call this cmdlet:
Get-Data -DataSource IMAP

how I try to add a logging feature within GetDataCmdlet class to log the full cmdlet being called. I know I can get the command names by:
string name = this.GetType().GetAttributeValue((CmdletAttribute cmd) => cmd.VerbName + "-" + cmd.NounName);

but how about the parameters and their values? I can do a hard code thing to get the data value, but it will be more complicate when parameter sets and optional parameters are used. Is it some method to auto retrieve these info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than deriving from [`Cmdlet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.cmdlet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), derive from its subclass [`PSCmdlet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/System.Management.Automation.PSCmdlet%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which adds many more functions (but adds a requirement, over `Cmdlet` to be called from the PowerShell runtime).

In particular [`PSCmdlet.MyInvocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.myinvocation%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives access to an instance of [`InvocationInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with two collections [`BoundParameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.boundparameters%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (parameters connected to cmdlet parameters) and [`UnboundArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/system.management.automation.invocationinfo.unboundarguments%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (everything else).

This is the internal equivalent to `$MyInvocation` in PowerShell itself.